# ASIHttpRequest NetworkQueue problem

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, asihttprequest

I want to use the ASIHttprequest library to download some files, I am testing with their code and it is not working while the same code works on their sample

this is my code to call their view

> QueueViewController
>   *queueViewController =    [[QueueViewController alloc]
>   initWithNibName:@"Queue" bundle:nil];
>     [self.view
>   addSubview:queueViewController.view];

This the code to make the request

```
- (IBAction)fetchThreeImages:(id)sender
{
    [imageView1 setImage:nil];
    [imageView2 setImage:nil];
    [imageView3 setImage:nil];

    [networkQueue cancelAllOperations];
    [networkQueue setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressIndicator];
    [networkQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(imageFetchComplete:)];
    [networkQueue setShowAccurateProgress:[accurateProgress isOn]];
    [networkQueue setDelegate:self];

    ASIHTTPRequest *request;
    request = [[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com/i/logo.png"]] autorelease];
    [networkQueue addOperation:request];

    request = [[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com/i/trailsnetwork.png"]] autorelease];
    [networkQueue addOperation:request];

    request = [[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com/i/sharedspace20.png"]] autorelease];
    [networkQueue addOperation:request];

    [networkQueue go];

}


- (void)imageFetchComplete:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[request responseData]];
    if (img) {
        if ([imageView1 image]) {
            if ([imageView2 image]) {
                [imageView3 setImage:img];
            } else {
                [imageView2 setImage:img];
            }
        } else {
            [imageView1 setImage:img];
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like the queue is being setup properly but imageFetchComplete method is not being called when the download is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the issue fixed, the problem was that I was not alloc networkQueue.

I was alloc   networkQueue in the awakefromnib it wasn't being called. So I alloc networkQueue in the button click method. That fixEd the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `requestDidFailSelector` on your instance of `ASINetworkQueue`, as well as setting `didFinishSelector` and `didFailSelector` on each instance of `ASIHTTPRequest`. Call NSLog() from each of those callback methods in your delegate to see what's happening.

Note that by enabling `showAccurateProgress` on your `ASINetworkQueue`, an additional HEAD request is done for every request that the queue processes. This can sometimes be less than ideal in a mobile context.